# can't run wkhtmltopdf from a cronjob

Tags: linux, pdf, cron, wkhtmltopdf

I got a command line.. When running it from `putty` it works, but when running the command from a cronjob (webmin) running as `root` the command hangs and never completes executing..

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /root/input.html /root/output.pdf
```

## update

Command line in `cronjob.php`

```
echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /root/input.html /root/output.pdf');
```

Command for the cron job (running as `root`)

```
php -f /var/cronjob.php
```

When the cron job is running from `webmin` the execution never completes, but when running the exact same command from `putty` it works! This is the output

```
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)
Done
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError
```

Running the command (without wkhtmltopdf) from both `putty` and `webmin` works

```
echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16"');
```

this is the output

```
xvfb-run: usage error: need a command to run
Usage: xvfb-run [OPTION ...] COMMAND
Run COMMAND (usually an X client) in a virtual X server environment.
...
```

When adding `wkhtmltopdf` the cronjob never completes

## update II

This command line doesn't work either from a cron job

```
xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf -h
```

## @ Grokify

```
echo shell_exec('0 0 * * * * xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf /var/www/tmp/test.html /var/www/tmp/output.pdf >> /var/www/tmp/pdf.log 2>> /var/www/tmp/pdf.err');
```

pdf.err

```
sh: 1: 0: not found
```

Comment: Can you put the full cron tab entry and what cron file its is in. Have you tried redirecting the output to a file and see if there is any output or errors?

Comment: how to redirect the output/errors to a file?

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Comment: like this? `xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf tmp/input.html tmp/output.pdf 2>&1 output.txt`

Comment: for errors: `command 2> output.txt`, for regular output: `command > output.txt`, for both: `command &> output.txt`

Comment: Ok, have now redirected stderr to a file.. When running the cronjob the file is created but empty.. the cronjob never completes

Comment: Just a little question: why do you run wkhtmltopdf with an X-Display? The project page states: "they run entirely "headless" and do not require a display or display service".

Comment: no.. debian repos does not run headless

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the PHP `shell_exec` syntax than works for me. The syntax starting with `0 0 * * *` is `cron` syntax in the event you wanted to edit the crontab directly.

Answer (score 1):

The cronjob may not be pulling in the environment of the user and therefor doesn't know what $PATH actually contains. I've found I need to use the full path to binaries in my crons:

```
2 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/cronjob.php
```

Answer (score 0):

whats the user the `cron` is running as? it may be a permission issue. try to use `sudo` to give power to create the full file.

So in the `cron` have

```
sudo xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf input.html output.pdf
```

you should consider putting xvfb-run in a full path like `/usr/bin/xvfb-run` or `/bin/xvfb-run` and when you specify input.html and output.pdf try to put its full path like `/home/user/Documents/input.html /home/user/Documents/output.pdf`

Comment: `sudo` returns `-bash: sudo: command not found`.. The cron job is running as `root`

Comment: you don't have sudo on the server, its ok. If its running as root make sure the folder where its writing the file is user accessible; can you also issue chmod 777 on the folder to give it all permission to test. if you're logged in as the user and you issue the command line manually and it works make sure to run it as that user if that doesn't work.

Comment: check my update again.. when running `php -f /var/cronjob.php` from putty it works, but it doesn't work when the cron job is executing the command

Answer (score 0):

The following PHP and crontab examples work for me both as unprivileged and privileged users. The example redirects `STDOUT` to `/tmp/pdf.log` and `STDERR` to `/tmp/pdf.err` to capture and examine logging and error messages. This example assumes `xvfb-run` and `wkhtmltopdf` are in your PATH which can be hard coded as well.

**PHP**

```
echo shell_exec('xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf /var/www/tmp/test.html /var/www/tmp/output.pdf >> /var/www/tmp/pdf.log 2>> /var/www/tmp/pdf.err');
```

**crontab**

```
0 0 * * * xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf /var/www/test.html /var/www/output.pdf >> /var/www/tmp/pdf.log 2>> /var/www/tmp/pdf.err
```

**STDOUT: wkhtmltopdf Success**

When run, the following appearing in `/var/www/tmp/pdf.log` indicating success which the error file remains empty:

```
$ cat /var/www/tmp/pdf.log
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)                                                 
Done
```

**STDOUT: wkhtmltopdf Error**

If there's a `wkhtmltopdf` error, it appears in `STDOUT` as well. The following is an example file not found error for `test.html` if the input file (`/var/www/tmp/test.html`) doesn't exist:

```
$ cat /var/www/tmp/pdf.log
Loading page (1/2)
Error: Failed loading page http:///var/www/tmp/test.html (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --ignore-load-errors)
[============================================================] 100%
```

Try adding the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` redirects to capture and check for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume problems with the (reduced) environment of cron and, subsequently, with xauth.

The way, I would try to gain progress is

(a) use the option `--error-file=/tmp/xvfb.log` of xvfb-run to see, what it says, and

(b) use the option `--auth-file=/path/to/root_s_home/.Xauthority` of xvfb-run

Another way round may be the installation of `wkthtmltopdf` from sources to get a real "headless" program without the need of `xvfb-run`

(These are just suggestions - I don't have chances to build a test scenario...)